How to derive this vector analysis equation?
How to use mathematica to derive this vector equation:
\begin{equation}
\nabla \times (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) = (\mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{A} - (\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{A} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}) - \mathbf{B} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A})
\end{equation}
I tried to calculate the left hand side but can never simplify it to the right hand side form. Can someone help:(

In what sense are you trying to use Mathematica here?  Are you trying to do this symbolically, or is it okay to do things component-wise? If it's the latter, you can just compute both sides and show that they're equal. If it's the former, you'll have to tell Mathematica  some rules about vector derivative manipulation.

@march I am really curious to know how to do it symbolically.

The object is a product, so the product rule applies. The double cross product is a linear combination of the two inner vectors. So you have by expansion of the triple cross product with indexed $\nabla_k$ as targeted derivative in a product only differentiating the indexed factor
   ∇×(A×B)=  ∇_1×(A×B) + ∇_2×(A×B)   ==
   (B .∇ ) A - B (∇. A) + A (∇.B ) - (A.∇) B

As a Mathematica proof you may use full throttle
  Curl[Cross[Subscript[A, #][x, y, z] & /@ Range[3], 
             Subscript[B, #][x, y, z] & /@ Range[3]], {x, y,z}] /. 
       {Derivative[n__][Subscript[a_, k_]][__] :> Subscript[a,  k, {x, y, z} . {n}], 
         Subscript[a_, k_][__] -> Subscript[a, k]} // FullSimplify

$$  
\left(\begin{array}{c}
-B_1 \left(A_{2,y}+A_{3,z}\right)+
  A_1 \left(B_{2,y}+B_{3,z}\right)+
  B_2 A_{1,y}-A_2 B_{1,y}+B_3 A_{1,z}-A_3 B_{1,z}\\
  -B_2 \left(A_{1,x}+A_{3,z}\right)+
   A_2 \left(B_{1,x}+B_{3,z}\right)+
   B_1 A_{2,x}-A_1 B_{2,x}+B_3 A_{2,z}-A_3 B_{2,z}\\
  -B_3 \left(A_{1,x}+A_{2,y}\right)+
   A_3 \left(B_{1,x}+B_{2,y}\right)+B_1 A_{3,x}-
A_1 B_{3,x}+B_2 A_{3,y}-A_2 B_{3,y}
\end{array}\right) $$
and similar for the other form.
